# Grails Spring securiy authentication with three parameters

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-domain-class

Currently I have a domain model of User as follows:

```
class User {
  transient springSecurityService

  String username
  String password
  String firstName
  String lastName
  boolean enabled = true

  static transients = ['springSecurityService', 'enabled']

  static constraints = {
      username blank: false, unique: true
      password blank: false
  }

}
```

And Spring security authentication with Role, UserRole models are working fine.
But I need to override User authentication with username and password along with emailID, email ID will be unique and it is a foreign key.

New User domain model is

```
class User {

  transient neatEncryptedType
  transient springSecurityService

  String username
  String password
  String emailId
  String firstName
  String lastName
  boolean enabled = true
}
```

How can I do this authentication using email, username and password?
Please anyone suggest how to override spring security authentication for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a talk a while back about the inner workings of the Spring Security plugins, and one example I did was a custom login with a 3rd parameter. There are a few steps involved to support this, so check out the downloadable code from [this blog post](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1090) for the process. It's not difficult, but requires a custom Authentication class, and custom filter and authenticator. But they're all based on existing classes, so it's all straightforward.